# Visual Studio 2019: Code Coverage Results says "Not Covered" despite unit tests existing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core, code-coverage

I have a .NET Core (`net5.0`) Visual Studio 2019 API project with an MSTest unit test project.  I also have a solution-wide `codecoverage.runsettings` file.  The problem is that, even though I've mocked (using the `Moq` Nuget Package) and written unit tests for all of my public Controller methods, have decorated my Controller's private methods with `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`, and have added exclusions in my `.runsettings` file, the Code Coverage Results window still shows 0% coverage:

[image]

(Note that I have blacked out the top-level namespace and other potentially sensitive information).

You will notice that my Controller class is listed twice (`SpliceController.<>c` and just plain old `SpliceController`.....I have no idea what the `<>c` means).  All the methods under `SpliceController.<>c`*do* in fact have associated unit tests (you will also notice that the method `UploadAttachments` is listed multiple times for some reason).  Under `SpliceController` the single method `GetUserNameFromClaims` is a private helper method decorated with `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` so it should not be in this list.  Notice that everything is listed as "not covered".

If it helps, here is the CodeCoverage section of my `.runsettings` file:

```
            <CodeCoverage>
              <ModulePaths>
                <Include>
                  <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
                  <ModulePath>.*\.exe$</ModulePath>
                </Include>
                <Exclude>
                  <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
                  <ModulePath>.*Splice.API.Model.dll</ModulePath>
                  <ModulePath>.*Splice.API.Test.dll</ModulePath>
                  <ModulePath>.*moq\.dll$</ModulePath>
                  <ModulePath>.*newtonsoft\.json\.dll$</ModulePath>
                  <ModulePath>.*netcore\.dll$</ModulePath>
                </Exclude>
              </ModulePaths>
              <Functions>
                <Exclude>  
                  <Function>.*MoveNext.*</Function>
                  <Function>.*DisplayClass.*</Function>
                  <Function>.*Services\.</Function>
                  <Function>.*Response\.</Function>
                  <Function>.*Migrations\.</Function>
                  <Function>.*Helpers\.</Function>
                  <Function>.*Filter\.</Function>
                  <Function>.*Startup\.</Function>
                  <Function>.*Program\.</Function>
                  <Function>.*EF\.</Function>
                </Exclude>
              </Functions>
              <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
              <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
              <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
              <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
            </CodeCoverage>
```

Comment: The `<c>` classes and methods are from delegates that were compiled. EIther aen anonymous parameter to a `Func<>`, `Action<T>`, `Task<T>` or in a LINQ statement for example. In certain cases (when variables are captured generally), the compiler will generate a special class under the hood to support a language feature that doesn't translate 1-to-1 to a CLR feature. See also: https://vkontech.com/the-intuitive-guide-to-understanding-closures-in-c/ Not that it explains why coverage isn't working, but it gives you more context on what you're seeing.

Comment: What could be happening is that the delegate is never evaluated. And therefore never runs, or that the delegate code is parsed and translated into something else, therefore never runs as MSIL, but a SQL for example. It's hard to tell without knowing the contents of that code under test.